# click php button to display web content on full screen

Tags: javascript, php

I work on quiz system and I want when user clicks start, then whole content show on full screen and if user close full screen view then quiz will be ended

Nothing happens when the button is clicked

index.php

```
<form method="POST" >
  <div class="left">
    <h1>Sign up</h1>

    <h2>Fullscreen with JavaScript</h2>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign me up" />


  </div>
</form>

<?php


  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elem = document.documentElement;
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is the ; doing in `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  ;?>` Also never use name="submit" if you want to ever submit the form using script

Comment: i remove that but script can't work

Comment: have a look at the code here which works http://robnyman.github.io/fullscreen/

Comment: its cant helpfull bro